# Issue with appsettings.Development.json when publishing a ASP.NET Core Worker Service as a single file

Tags: .net-core

I'm publishing an ASP.NET Core Worker Service as a single file and have the below code in my csproj file so that the appsettings.json file is not included in the single file and can be changed as required when deployed.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

However, I'm finding that even though I'm publishing as "Release" configuration the service is referring to appsettings.Development.json

I currently work around this by also adding the below code to my csproj file however that doesn't hit me as the correct approach.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I didn't need the below

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Instead, I had to change the below in Program.cs

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()  
    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)  
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", true);
_configuration = builder.Build();
```

to

```
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT");

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()  
    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)  
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true);
_configuration = builder.Build();
```

No doubt there's a better way to do the above however it is working as required now.